# Calling method which creates thread multiple times

Tags: c, pthreads

I have code in which `main()` that is calling `function_one()`. In `function_one()`, I am creating a thread and calling function `function_two()`.  Now the problem is that `main()` is calling `function_one()` multiple times and `function_one()` is creating a new thread each time it's called.  In this code, I can't use more than 4 threads and I can't change `main()`. Is there any way that I can re-use a thread that is being created during a previous call to `function_one()`?

This is pseudo code for what I'm working with:

```
main()
{
    int x=1,y=2;
    while(1) {
        x++;y++;
        function_one(x,y);
    }
}

function_one(int x, int y)
{
    pthread_t ax;    //initialization is missing
    pthread_create(ax,NULL,&function_two,NULL);
}

function_two()
{
   //some operation
}
```

Comment: Note that you use: `pthread_t ax; pthread_create(&ax, NULL, function_two, NULL);` where the ampersand before `&ax` is not optional, and the one before `function_two` is).  And your compiler should be telling you that you miscalled `pthread_create()`.  If it isn't, there's something seriously wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need worker threads, and condition_variables to wake up your worker threads.

```
pthread_cond_t new_value_cv;
bool exit_flag;


int main(){
    exit_flag=false;
    pthread_t ax[4];    //initialization is missing
    for(int i=0;i<4; i++){
        pthread_create(ax[i],NULL,&function_two,NULL);
    }
    int x=1,y=2;
    while(1) {
        x++;y++;
        function_one(x,y);
    }

}


function_one(int x, int y)
{
    pthread_cond_signal(&new_value_cv);
}



function_two()
{
   pthread_mutex_t wait_mutex;

   while(1){   
      pthread_cond_wait(&new_value_cv, &wait_mutex);
      if (exit_flag) break;   

     //do_something
   }
}
```

If you need `function_two()` to take arguments, you need to check the *consumer/producer pattern*. specifically a **single producer / multiple consumer** pattern. The basic idea is to use a thread safe queue shared by `main` and your 4 child threads to distribute the values.